# Solving an ODE when the function is given as discrete values -matlab-

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I have the following ODE:

```
x_dot = 3*x.^0.5-2*x.^1.5  % (Equation 1)
```

I am using `ode45` to solve it. My solution is given as a vector of dim(k x 1) (usually k = 41, which is given by the `tspan`).

On the other hand, I have made a model that approximates the model from (1), but in order to compare how accurate this second model is, I want to solve it (solve the second ODE) by means of `ode45`. My problem is that this second ode is given discrete:

```
x_dot = f(x) % (Equation 2)
```

`f` is discrete and not a continuous function like in (1). The values I have for `f` are:

```
0.5644
0.6473
0.7258
0.7999
0.8697
0.9353
0.9967
1.0540
1.1072
1.1564
1.2016
1.2429
1.2803
1.3138
1.3435
1.3695
1.3917
1.4102
1.4250
1.4362
1.4438
1.4477
1.4482
1.4450
1.4384
1.4283
1.4147
1.3977
1.3773
1.3535
1.3263
1.2957
1.2618
1.2246
1.1841
1.1403
1.0932
1.0429
0.9893
0.9325
0.8725
```

What I want now is to solve this second ode using `ode45`. Hopefully I will get a solution very similar that the one from (1). How can I solve a discrete ode applying `ode45`? Is it possible to use `ode45`? Otherwise I can use `Runge-Kutta` but I want to be fair comparing the two methods, which means that I have to solve them by the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to create an interpolated lookup table function:

```
fx = [0.5644 0.6473 0.7258 0.7999 0.8697 0.9353 0.9967 1.0540 1.1072 1.1564 ...
      1.2016 1.2429 1.2803 1.3138 1.3435 1.3695 1.3917 1.4102 1.4250 1.4362 ...
      1.4438 1.4477 1.4482 1.4450 1.4384 1.4283 1.4147 1.3977 1.3773 1.3535 ...
      1.3263 1.2957 1.2618 1.2246 1.1841 1.1403 1.0932 1.0429 0.9893 0.9325 0.8725];
x = 0:0.25:10
f = @(xq)interp1(x,fx,xq);
```

Then you should be able to use `ode45` as normal:

```
tspan = [0 1];
x0 = 2;
xout = ode45(@(t,x)f(x),tspan,x0);
```

Note that you did not specify what values of of `x` your function (`fx` here) is evaluated over so I chose zero to ten. You'll also not want to use the copy-and-pasted values from the command window of course because they only have four decimal places of accuracy. Also, note that because `ode45` required the inputs `t` and then `x`, I created a separate anonymous function using `f`, but `f` can created with an unused  `t` input if desired.

Comment: Hi again horchler. Your suggestion works perfectly! and the solution of my approximation is promising! My supervisor would be very happy. Thank you again!

Comment: My problem is now the following:
For my x value (for the fx function) I have being using the same domain x(t) has, x(t) is the solution (after ode45) of my first equation (1.-). I have now change the tspan and x0 to see how well my model approximates the solutions of this first ODE and for some tspan and x0 I have nice results, but for other i get NAN from the interp1. I know that the domain of x(t), varies accordingly when tspan and x0 varies. I am applying this changes to my value of x, but I am still getting NAN for the interp1. Do you understand my problem @horchler?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SergioSarmiento: Please look at the help for [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). A value of `NaN` is returned by default for extrapolated values, i.e., your input `xp` is less than `min(x)` or greater than `max(x)`. You'll either need to generate new values for `fx` over a wider range of `x` or you can look into using the `'extrap'` option within `interp1` (just be aware that extrapolation won't be very accurate far from the range of `x`).

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but I have a question which is based on THIS question from the last year. In your answer you are giving me the solution to how to send a discrete function to ode45. What I have now is a system of (5x5) odes. If you see your answer, this will mean that I have: `fx1,fx2,fx3,fx4,fx5` and `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5`. Which are the function values and the points where the functions where evaluated. My question: How can I solve this system by **ode45**? I can not interpolate each equation and send to ode45. I have to solve it as a system, but I don't know how to do it...