# Reading a file that corresponds to time step in solving ODE

Tags: matlab, ode, sampling

I'm trying to solve an ODE in Matlab and I have the following problem:
my code is as bellow:

```
xinit=[0.19;25;0;7];
t=0:768:76800; %% 101 cells
[t1,y]=ode45(@Model_Bio,t,xinit);
```

In the function @Model_Bio I have a parameter that I need to read its corresponding values for each time step (101 values)!
So, My @Model_Bio is somehow as bellow:

```
load 'mydata'
a=mydata;    
.....
```

the problem is that, when I execute the ode45(@Model_Bio,t,xinit), it calls my function with an automated time step (for example 50 times!) and my problem is that I cannot assign the values for each of my time step (101)!
Also, I think its not a good idea to change the time step of the ode the same as my 101 steps! 
Anyone that help me on this is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to provide a wrapper of your data that interpolates it for arbitrary t, for example

my_interp = @(t) interp1(my_data_t, my_data_x, t)

http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

and then implement your RHS (@Model_Bio) in terms of my_interp

Comment: Agreed. There are plenty of similar questions like this, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231703/solving-a-system-of-odes-where-the-functions-are-given-discrete-matlab or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732442/solving-an-ode-when-the-function-is-given-as-discrete-values-matlab.

Comment: it sounds like a popular question:)