# Solving ODE in MATLAB with a function that its numerical value can be evaluated everywhere

Tags: matlab, solver, ode

For example, if I have the following ODE:
y''+y=0

In Matlab I could assume y(1)=y and y(2)=y', then

dy(1)=y(2)

dy(2)=-y(1)

Now, if I have the ODE in the form of y''+f(x)*y=0, where f(x) is a function that I can evaluate its numerical value anywhere but you don't have the analytical form and can't fit f(x) to a certain function. My question is then how to numerically solve this ODE in MATLAB if I want to put the value of f(x) in the ODE, for example,

f(x)=0.1 when x<0.5 and

f(x)=1.0 when x>=0.5

This ODE might be unrealistic but it gives an idea about the problem I am facing. Please don't solve it piecewise. Is that doable? Or I have to write the ODE solver by myself?

Thanks in advance for the inputs.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you just have data for f(x)? I assume that you have many more points than just two like in your example and that the data   are discrete samples from an underlying smooth function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving an ODE when the function is given as discrete values -matlab-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732442/solving-an-ode-when-the-function-is-given-as-discrete-values-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same trick. Call y → y(1) and y' → y(2). Then

d/dx y(1) = y(2)

d/dx y(2) = - f(x) * y(1)

Implement a function

```
function dy = myodefun(x, y)
dy = zeros(2, 1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = - f(x) * y(1);
```

or explicitly for your example

```
function dy = myodefun(x, y)
dy = zeros(2, 1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = - (0.1 + (x >= 0.5) * 0.9) * y(1);
```

and give it to a standard solver, e.g. `ode45`.

Comment: Thanks A. Donda. But what it f(x) is a vector with, say, 1000 data points? In the example I provided f(x) can still be written into a function, but what if f(x) can not be be explicitly expressed as a function?

Comment: Well you should have mentioned that in the question. They way you wrote it it seemed that you do have an implementation of `f(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I myself found a solution to this question:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?searchHighlight=interpolate

Interpolation has to be used. But seems like a feasible way.

Any other method is welcomed.